# Is there an official teaser poster for "The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair" film?

Tags: movie, the-chronicles-of-narnia

This [image on the WikiNarnia](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia:_The_Silver_Chair) appears to be an official teaser image for the 2016 film *The Chronicles of Narnia: The Silver Chair*, but I have not found any news source which announces any members of the cast. If this is an officially-released image, wouldn't these two actors be announced by this point? Is it simply a fan-made Photoshopped image?

[image: Silver Chair]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This seems to be a fan-made poster.**

It was made by a deviantART user called Omnipotrent. Their copy of the poster is here: http://omnipotrent.deviantart.com/art/The-Chronicles-of-Narnia-The-Silver-Chair-401179595. Quoting from the description:

> I think it's safe to assume that there will not be a fourth *Chronicles of Narnia* installment, however if their [sic] was, I chose Jamie Campbell Bower from City of Bones to play Caspian's missing son Prince Rillian.

As such, you shouldn’t read anything into the actors portrayed in that image. (Although within a month or so of this poster being made, the 2016 movie was announced, so who knows.)

Source: I used [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com) to look up the image, and that dA page was the first result.

Comment: Also, that's clearly Tilda Swinton, who played the White Witch in *TLtWatW*, but the White Witch is not a character in *The Silver Chair*.